# How to set date range for @Consumption.filter.defaultValue?

Tags: sapui5, abap, sap-fiori, cds

I'm using the ABAP Restful Application Programming Model - oData v2.

I'd like to be able to default in a date range of say, a CreationDate within the last 3 months.

At a very basic level, I can default in a single arbitrary date, see my CDS View below...

```
 @Consumption.filter.defaultValue: '20201012000000'  
 CreationDate : rap_cp_odata_v2_edm_datetime ;
```

Could you please provide an example of how a date range could be set up using Today's date going back 3 months rather than having to provide a literal value?

Answer (score 0):

Add this against `Date` field -

```
@Consumption.filter.selectionType: #INTERVAL
```